# proxy connection error with tinyproxy

Tags: python, proxy, pythonanywhere, tinyproxy

My first post/question to stackoverflow, please bear with me.

**Project/Objective:**
I have a python script on pythonanywhere which uses an API get request which requires an ip specific key.  However, when the script is run from pythonanywhere, the ip is dynamic.  I am able to work around using an open proxy server and specifying the proxy server's ip in the request header and generating the API key with the proxy server's ip.  I thought a better solution would be to set up a proxy server of my own at home.

**Attempted Solution:**
Running tinyproxy on ubuntu 16.04 behind a router with port forwarding set on 8888 to the internal ip of the ubuntu machine.
tinyproxy config settings as follows:
Port 8888
ConnectPort 443
ConnectPort 563
Allow 127.0.0.1
Allow xx.xx.xx.xx (my external ip)
Allow 192.168..0.0/16

**Sample Code:**

```
import requests
proxy_ip = 'xx.xx.xx.xx:8888' # my external ip
proxy = {
    'http': proxy_ip,
    'https': proxy_ip
    }
r = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org',params={'format': 'json'},proxies=proxy)
my_proxied_ip = r.json()['ip']
print('my proxied ip: ' + my_proxied_ip)
```

**Problem:**
If I use a known open proxy ip:port... works fine.
If I xx.xx.xx.xx:8888... I get:
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?format=json (Caused 
by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Access denied',)))

**Question:**
I am striking out with troubleshooting... seems like it's a problem with the proxy server (tinyproxy) settings.  Or is there something else I'm missing?  Or a better solution / workaround?

Comment: Are you on a free PythonAnywhere account? If so PythonAnywhere puts free users through their own proxy and you can only access whitelisted sites.

Comment: No. I'm on a paid account.

Comment: does the request ever get to your local machine?

Comment: Did you check the logs at /var/log/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.log If you are using VPN the ip may be different when it reaches to tinyproxy